# How does Chrome know to provide Client Certificate when no "Client Request" is sent in handshake?

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, wireshark, tls1.2, mutual-authentication

This question has puzzled me while looking into a Mutual SSL failure between my client app and an external Server.

When my app tries to connection to the external server's rest API - let's call it https://www.server.com/api/resolve - I expect a "Certificate Request" handshake element to be sent with their Server hello. As far as I can tell from a tcpdump of all traffic between me and the server, it is not sent. Only a "Server Hello, Certificate, Certificate Status, Server Key Exchange, Server Hello Done" is sent:

tcpdump of TLSv1.2 handshake: https://i.stack.imgur.com/50Ous.png

However when I try to access that same API URL in Chrome, the browser displays a box asking me to select my client certificate for mutual authentication. When I capture a dump of that handshake up to the point where the browser prompts me for a certificate, I still see no "Certificate Request" sent by the Server:

Tcpdump of browser navigation to API: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvOEx.png

After selecting a certificate in Chrome, I'm directed to the site, however I see no Client "Certificate" sent in my TLS1.2 capture either.

**My question is, is there any way can Chrome know a client cert was requested by the server if that request is not sent in the TLS handshake?**

Alternatively, is it possible wireshark is lying to me? When I test against, for example: https://client.badssl.com/ which requests Mutual SSL, I see the Certificate Request right after the Server Key Exchange exactly as I should. I noticed in the TLSv1.2 RFC (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246) it notes:

> "In particular, the certificate and certificate request
> handshake messages can be large enough to require fragmentation."

But this should be irrelevant to how Wireshark is displaying the TLS info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several *Encrypted Handshake Message* in the packet capture after the application data. This very likely means that the server itself does not request a client certificate by default but that the certificate is only requested for specific URL.

In this case first a TLS handshake is done without a *CertificateRequest*. Once the handshake is finished the client sends the HTTP request over the encrypted connection which is the *Application Data* in the packet capture. The server will determine that the requested URL needs a client certificate and initiate a renegotiation, i.e. another TLS handshake but this time with a *CertificateRequest*. But since the connection is already encrypted this renegotiation is only visible as *Encrypted Handshake Message* and the details cannot be seen without decrypting the traffic.

Comment: @MrEmployee: How exactly should this link help with this particular problem? The OP already seems to have a sufficient understanding of how client certificates are requested. And the topic of renegotiation (which is essential in this case) is not addressed by the link you've provided.